# nodejs: are TCP messages sent/received atomically?

Tags: node.js, tcp

Consider following example:

**server:**

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(connection) { 
   console.log('client connected');
   connection.on('end', function() {
      console.log('client disconnected');
   });
   connection.write('Hello World!\r\n');
   connection.pipe(connection);
});
server.listen(8080, function() { 
  console.log('server is listening');
});
```

**client:**

```
var net = require('net');
var client = net.connect({port: 8080}, function() {
   console.log('connected to server!');  
});
client.on('data', function(data) {
   console.log(data.toString());
   client.end();
});
client.on('end', function() { 
   console.log('disconnected from server');
});
```

Is it guaranteed that the message ***'Hello World!\r\n'*** from the client will be received atomically in one message when ***client.on('data', ...)*** is called? Or do I have to store all messages in a temporary buffer and specify my own "start" and "end" pattern to recognize that a complete message was received?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, its not guaranteed with TCP protocol. TCP is streaming protocol, which means it could accumulate multiple `write()`s in your code in internal TCP buffer. It writes those chunks in order and doesn't respect your message boundaries.

Same thing happens in the client end. You could receive multiple `write()` chunks in one `data` event.

You need to implement your own protocol to identify each message. Google for `tcp message boundary problem` to find some implementation examples.